# HTML/CSS: How to make a bar on the side to take you to a certain part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhm2Q.png)

How would I make something like this so when you scroll the dots show you where you are on the page and click it to take you to that section?

Also do you use javascript if you want the page to scroll to a section instead of just appearing on it?

Comment: I don't understand to what extent is the answer you're looking for but my laziest advice will be 'Look at a template with similar functionality'

Comment: This is a kind of scroll spy and also js can also scrolling to the section in a page

Comment: It's an image. Where's the site that it is on?

Comment: This feature is called scroll spy. Bootstrap has it if it's an option, [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty version - there are probably better ways to do stuff, but this works (you can use :before / :after pseudo-classes if you want and use icons/font-awesome for the circles, that way you can lose at least the `<i>`element. But I was too lazy to make that.

(This has been edited slightly to cater for on-page elements, instead of between pages)

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  }
h2,p {
  margin-left: 10em;
  }
#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 1em;
  top: 15%;
  }
#menu li {;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: .25em 0;
  }
#menu li i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
#menu li span {
  display: none;
  }
#menu li:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 1em;
  }
#menu li:hover i {
  background: white;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#first"><i></i><span>First item</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#second"><i></i><span>Second</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#third"><i></i><span>Third item</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#fourth"><i></i><span>Fourth</span></a></li>
</ul>

<h2 id="first">First item</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In schola desinis. Quos quidem tibi studiose et diligenter tractandos magnopere censeo. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Graecis hoc modicum est: Leonidas, Epaminondas, tres aliqui aut quattuor; Ea possunt paria non esse. Sed haec quidem liberius ab eo dicuntur et saepius. Si verbum sequimur, primum longius verbum praepositum quam bonum. Invidiosum nomen est, infame, suspectum. Paria sunt igitur. </p>

<p>Apparet statim, quae sint officia, quae actiones. Septem autem illi non suo, sed populorum suffragio omnium nominati sunt. Huic mori optimum esse propter desperationem sapientiae, illi propter spem vivere. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. </p>
<h2 id="second">Second item</h2>
<p>Illa tamen simplicia, vestra versuta. Eorum enim omnium multa praetermittentium, dum eligant aliquid, quod sequantur, quasi curta sententia; Tum Quintus: Est plane, Piso, ut dicis, inquit. Erit enim mecum, si tecum erit. Primum in nostrane potestate est, quid meminerimus? Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est. Est enim tanti philosophi tamque nobilis audacter sua decreta defendere. Varietates autem iniurasque fortunae facile veteres philosophorum praeceptis instituta vita superabat. </p>

<p>Sed tamen enitar et, si minus multa mihi occurrent, non fugiam ista popularia. Consequens enim est et post oritur, ut dixi. Ut proverbia non nulla veriora sint quam vestra dogmata. Itaque eos id agere, ut a se dolores, morbos, debilitates repellant. Quae contraria sunt his, malane? In his igitur partibus duabus nihil erat, quod Zeno commutare gestiret. </p>
<h2 id="third">Third item</h2>
<p>Quo modo autem optimum, si bonum praeterea nullum est? Philosophi autem in suis lectulis plerumque moriuntur. Duarum enim vitarum nobis erunt instituta capienda. Sed haec nihil sane ad rem; Obsecro, inquit, Torquate, haec dicit Epicurus? Age nunc isti doceant, vel tu potius quis enim ista melius? </p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In schola desinis. Quos quidem tibi studiose et diligenter tractandos magnopere censeo. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Graecis hoc modicum est: Leonidas, Epaminondas, tres aliqui aut quattuor; Ea possunt paria non esse. Sed haec quidem liberius ab eo dicuntur et saepius. Si verbum sequimur, primum longius verbum praepositum quam bonum. Invidiosum nomen est, infame, suspectum. Paria sunt igitur. </p>

<p>Apparet statim, quae sint officia, quae actiones. Septem autem illi non suo, sed populorum suffragio omnium nominati sunt. Huic mori optimum esse propter desperationem sapientiae, illi propter spem vivere. Illum mallem levares, quo optimum atque humanissimum virum, Cn. </p>
<h2 id="fourth">Fourth item</h2>
<p>Illa tamen simplicia, vestra versuta. Eorum enim omnium multa praetermittentium, dum eligant aliquid, quod sequantur, quasi curta sententia; Tum Quintus: Est plane, Piso, ut dicis, inquit. Erit enim mecum, si tecum erit. Primum in nostrane potestate est, quid meminerimus? Eadem nunc mea adversum te oratio est. Est enim tanti philosophi tamque nobilis audacter sua decreta defendere. Varietates autem iniurasque fortunae facile veteres philosophorum praeceptis instituta vita superabat. </p>

<p>Sed tamen enitar et, si minus multa mihi occurrent, non fugiam ista popularia. Consequens enim est et post oritur, ut dixi. Ut proverbia non nulla veriora sint quam vestra dogmata. Itaque eos id agere, ut a se dolores, morbos, debilitates repellant. Quae contraria sunt his, malane? In his igitur partibus duabus nihil erat, quod Zeno commutare gestiret. </p>

<p>Quo modo autem optimum, si bonum praeterea nullum est? Philosophi autem in suis lectulis plerumque moriuntur. Duarum enim vitarum nobis erunt instituta capienda. Sed haec nihil sane ad rem; Obsecro, inquit, Torquate, haec dicit Epicurus? Age nunc isti doceant, vel tu potius quis enim ista melius? </p>
```

Comment: I don't think is the question they asked.

Comment: Oh, right. "on the page". Exactly same principle, though, you would just need to change the href to an existing id on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to jump from one place to another in your page I would add `<a name="label"></a>` to the code where you start talking about another subject. If you do choose to do this just add a link where ever you want but it goes like this `<a href="#lable">link-name</a>` does this help? it might of not helped you on waht you wanted but your question was confusing and not clear on what you wanted. At least my idea could help you navigate on a long page that you may make/have.

J. Carter :)

Comment: Eh, no. You add an ID to whatever element you wanna scroll to, and then you do the `<a href="#whatever">` - you don't use `name`attributes, that's at least 7-8 years ago - at least.

Comment: it may be the same thing but in a newer way for me there is no difference.

Comment: There is a difference, it's called semantic structuring of the HTML, and using updated and proper techniques. Also, the "name"-attribute is not available for other elements than `form`-elements, and specific external elements, like `object` or `iframe` - specs here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_name.asp